# At a closed monoidal category, how can I derive a morphism $C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be objects of a [closed monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_monoidal_category) which is also bicartesian closed. How can I derive a morphism $C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$?

$(-)\times (-)$ denotes the product, $(-)+(-)$ the coproduct and $(-)^{(-)}$ the exponentiation.

Comment: Is $\times$ the product or the monoidal product?

Comment: I guess it is the monoidal product, since its right adjoint is exponentation. But, just out of curiosity, couldn't it be both the product and the monoidal product?

Comment: Okay, but does it coincide with the normal product, i.e. is the category cartesian closed?

Comment: Oh, yes it is. Actually, it is bicartesian closed.

Comment: Does the product commute with coproduct? If so then a map $$C^A×C^B→C^{A+B}$$ is the same as a map 
$$(C^A×C^B×A)+(C^A×C^B×B)\to C$$. But then you could use the projections followed by the evaluation maps, which then induce a map from the coproduct to $C$.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more explicit? The product does commute with the coproduct. Also, if you'd like, you could write a post as an answer, so that I accept it and give you some credit. Thanks for your interest. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cartesian* closure applies to *cartesian* categories, i.e. categories which are (symmetric) monoidal with respect to the (binary) product bifunctor (basically any finitely complete category is cartesian). Cartesian *closed* categories are those categories where each functor $A\times-$ has a right adjoint $(-)^A$ realizing the binatural bijection
$$
{\cal C}(A\times B,C)\cong {\cal C}(B, C^A)
$$
In this setting you can  exploit the fact that right adjoint preserve limits (being the bifunctor $(A,C)\mapsto C^A$ contravariant in $A$ this means that it sends colimits to limits): more precisely (I *love* these computations by nonsense!), in this particular case you have that
$$\begin{align*} 
{\cal C}(X, C^{A\coprod B}) & \cong {\cal C}(X\times(A\amalg B),C)\\
&\cong {\cal C}\Big((X\times A)\amalg(X\times B),C\Big)\\
&\cong {\cal C}\big(X\times A, C\big)\times {\cal C}\big(X\times B,C\big) \\
&\cong {\cal C}(X,C^A)\times {\cal C}(X,C^B) \\
&\cong {\cal C}(X,C^A\times C^B)
\end{align*}$$
Now you can conclude, since the Yoneda lemma tells you that the two objects you wanted to link are isomorphic (since they give rise to canonically isomorphic hom-presheaves).

This in fact works in more generality, i.e. in a (let's suppose: symmetric) monoidal category $\cal C$ such that the tensor functor $\otimes\colon (A,B)\mapsto A\otimes B$ gives rise to functors $A\otimes -$, each of which has a right adjoint $[A,-]$ (the "internal hom" in the monoidal category.

Comment: The thing is I'd like a solution in terms of morphisms. I mean, I need to find which is this morphism and not just if it exists. I have an arrow $\langle \tilde{h_1},\tilde{h_2}\rangle:D^C\to D^A\times D^B$. Now, I need to find this arrow I'm asking for, so that I compose it with this one and get an arrow from $D^C\to D^{A+B}$.

I should metion that $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the pairing of two arrows with a common domain, and $\tilde{f}:A\to C^B$ is currying of $f:A\times B\to C$.

Comment: Let me just point out that in the general monoidal setting, we still get an isomorphism $C^{A \sqcup B} = C^A \times C^B$ (not $C^{A \sqcup B} = C^A \otimes C^B$). This was asked in the comments.