# Proof of $C^{A+B} \cong C^{A} \times C^{B}$ using only UMP and definitions of products and exponential objects

Tags: category-theory

I need to show that in any category with binary products and coproducts, the following holds:

$C^{A+B} \cong C^{A} \times C^{B}$

using only universal mapping properties and definitions of (co)products and exponential objects.

I'm aware of this question:
[At a closed monoidal category, how can I derive a morphism $C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658848/at-a-closed-monoidal-category-how-can-i-derive-a-morphism-ca-times-cb-to-c),
but I'd like to look at a proof which does not involve the Yoneda lemma, right adjoints, binatural bijections etc.

As the problem statement
http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/SummerSchool/HW/cathw2.pdf 
tells us, it can be shown by "drawing commutative diagrams" only:

> There is no trick for this one -- you'll have to crank it out

Comment: What is your defintion of $C^A$? Normally, this involes adjoints, so you cannot except to prove something about it without knowing about them.

Comment: "I'd like to look at a proof which does not involve the Yoneda lemma," Why? The Yoneda Lemma is very simple. If you want to avoid it, you can only write down its proof in this special case. And that's also what the only possible proof can look like. You can find it on your own.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I can't provide any decent attempt to the solution." Why not? Of course you have to find two morphisms which are inverse to each other, and of course they can be constructed via the universal properties. And it is straight forward to do that. Please tell us what you have tried.

Comment: "can be constructed via the universal properties. And it is straight forward to do that." . This I have tried and it didn't work. If someone could make such construction, it would be great

Comment: It seems strange that the problem assumed only the existence of binary products and coproducts, not exponentials. It seems to tacitly assume the existence of $C^A$, $C^B$, and $C^{A+B}$, but even that's not entirely clear. Perhaps the mere existence of $C^A$ and $C^B$ is supposed to imply that their product serves as $C^{A+B}$. But even assuming the existence of all three exponentials, I don't see how to solve this without some distributivity, which I can prove (at the moment) only if some more exponentials are known to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is what I was asking for at first place, at the question you're linking. But then I saw it gets really messy without the Yoneda lemma.

My (incomplete) work on this was the following: You have to find isomorphic arrows $f:C^{A+B}\to C^A\times C^B$ and $g:C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$ such, that their composition gives the corresponding identity arrow.

- With $\pi_i:A_1\times A_2\to A_i$ I denote the projections of product $A_1\times A_2$.
- With $\kappa_i^{A_1,A_2}:A_i\to A_1+A_2$ I denote the coprojections of coproduct $A_1+A_2$.
- For $f:A\times B\to C$, I denote with $\tilde{f}: A\to C^B$ the currying of $f$ and, for $g:A\to C^B$, I denote with $\bar{g}:A\times B\to C$ its uncurrying.
- $\gamma$ is the braiding iso: $\gamma_{A,B}=\langle\pi_2^{A,B},\pi_1^{A,B}\rangle:A\times B\to B\times A$

### Finding $f$

We have $$\mathbf{1}_{C^{A+B}}\times \kappa_1^{A,B}:C^{A+B}\times A\to C^{A+B}\times(A+B)$$ and $$\mathbf{1}_{C^{A+B}}\times \kappa_2^{A,B}:C^{A+B}\times B\to C^{A+B}\times(A+B)$$

Then, put $h_i$ to be:
$$h_1=\varepsilon\circ(\mathbf{1}_{C^{A+B}}\times \kappa_1^{A,B}):C^{A+B}\times A\to C$$ and $$h_2=\varepsilon\circ(\mathbf{1}_{C^{A+B}}\times \kappa_2^{A,B}):C^{A+B}\times B\to C$$

So, by currying you get $\tilde{h_1}:C^{A+B}\to C^A$ and $\tilde{h_2}:C^{A+B}\to C^B$ and their product will be $$f=\langle\tilde{h_1}, \tilde{h_2}\rangle$$

### Finding $g$

You have $$\kappa_1^{(C^A\times C^B)\times A,(C^A\times C^B)\times B}\circ\gamma_{A,C^A\times C^B}:A\times(C^A\times C^B)\to ((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)$$ and
$$\kappa_2^{(C^A\times C^B)\times A,(C^A\times C^B)\times B}\circ\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B}:B\times(C^A\times C^B)\to ((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)$$

Then, take their currying and put
$$q_1=\widetilde{\kappa_1^{(C^A\times C^B)\times A,(C^A\times C^B)\times B}\circ\gamma_{A,C^A\times C^B}}:A\to \left(((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)\right)^{C^A\times C^B}$$ and $$q_2=\widetilde{\kappa_2^{(C^A\times C^B)\times A,(C^A\times C^B)\times B}\circ\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B}}:B\to \left(((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)\right)^{C^A\times C^B}$$
Their coproduct is $$[q_1,q_2]:A+B\to\left(((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)\right)^{C^A\times C^B}$$
Its exponential transpose then is a very helpful arrow (you can check that it is also an iso):
$$t=\overline{[q_1,q_2]}:C^A\times C^B\times (A+B)\to ((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)$$
Then, you can easily find the desired arrow $g:C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$ as the exponential transpose of the composition of $t$ with some other arrows including evaluation arrows $\varepsilon_{A,C}$ and $\varepsilon_{B,C}$.

You're not done yet. You have to show that $f\circ g=\mathbf{1}_{C^A\times C^B}$ and $g\circ f=\mathbf{1}_{C^{A+B}}$. At this point, I didn't bother verifying... I quit and just used the Yoneda lemma.

Comment: @ValerySaharov You have done a strange thing here: $$C^{A+B} \times (A+B) \cong X \times (A+B) \cong X \times A + X \times B \cong C^{A} \times A + C^{B} \times B$$ The first isomorphism implies $X\cong C^{A+B}$, but later you substitute $X$ with $C^A$ or $C^B$. Also, I don't see why to use an unrelated object $X$...

Comment: @ValerySaharov The construction is messy, arrows are getting too big to write down, and this makes things hard to manipulate. But this solution is indeed coming in a straightforward way from the corresponding solution with Yoneda's lemma.

Comment: Yes, I do use exponentials. You too say at the title to use UMPs of (co)products and exponentials.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Also, exponentials are assumed to exist, because if they didn't the question would lack of context. If $X=C^A$, $Y=C^B$ and $Z=C^{A+B}$ weren't exponentials, they would be some arbitrary objects... Then, the question "$Z=X\times Y~$? for arbitrary $X$,$Y$ and $Z$" would be meaningless.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Yes, you also need the exponentials that I use in the solution. Like, $\left(((C^A\times C^B)\times A)+((C^A\times C^B)\times B)\right)^{C^A\times C^B}$. But If you declare your category to "have exponentials" then it means that it has all finite exponentials, so this one included.