# $C^{A+B} \cong C^A \times C^B$ in a Cartesian Closed Category

Tags: category-theory

This is chapter 6 question 11c in Awodey's Category Theory textbook, and this comes before natural transformations, Yoneda lemma, and adjoints, so I'd like to avoid using those. I also just saw the question asked here [Proof of $C^{A+B} \cong C^{A} \times C^{B}$ using only UMP and definitions of products and exponential objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697774/proof-of-cab-cong-ca-times-cb-using-only-ump-and-definitions-of-pr) , however they only found the arrows which I believe to be the easy part, and didn't show that the arrows were inverses of each other

so far i have
$$
\hom(X, C^{A+B}) \cong \hom(X \times (A+B), C) \cong \hom(X \times A + X \times B, C) \cong \hom(X \times A, C) \times \hom(X \times B, C) \cong \hom(X, C^A) \times \hom(X, C^B) \cong \hom(X, C^A \times C^B)
$$

Let $\epsilon_{A+B} : C^{A+B} \times (A+B) \rightarrow C$, $\epsilon_A : C^A \times A \rightarrow C$, $\epsilon_B : C^B \times B \rightarrow C$ be evaluation arrows. What i do is i set $X = C^{A+B}$ and $X = C^A \times C^B$, and "trace the identity arrows through the isomorphisms." So starting from $1_{C^{A+B}}$, we go to $\epsilon_{A+B} \circ (1_{C^{A+B}} \times 1_{A+B}) = \epsilon_{A+B}$, then $\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f$ where $f : C^{A+B} \times A + C^{A+B} \times B \rightarrow C^{A+B} \times (A+B)$ is an isomorphism arrow(I already proved without using Yoneda, adjoints etc that $C \times (A+B) \cong C \times A + C \times B$),  then $\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_1, \epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_2$ where $i_1, i_2$ are injections, then $\widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_1}^A, \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_2}^B$, and finally we get $\langle \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_1}^A, \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_2}^B \rangle$.

For the other direction, we start off with $1_{C^A \times C^B}$, then $p_1,p_2$ where $p_1,p_2$ are the projections, then $\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B$, then $[\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B]$, then $[\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B] \circ g$ where $g : (C^A \times C^B) \times A + (C^A \times C^B) \times B \rightarrow (C^A + C^B) \times (A+B)$ is an isomorphism arrow, and finally $\widetilde{[\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B] \circ g}^{A+B}$.

However, I'm having trouble showing that these arrows are inverses of each other. I.e., I'm having troulbe showing $\langle \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_1}^A, \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_2}^B \rangle \circ \widetilde{[\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B] \circ g}^{A+B} = 1_{C^A \times C^B}$ and $\widetilde{[\epsilon_A \circ p_1 \times 1_A, \epsilon_B \circ p_2 \times 1_B] \circ g}^{A+B} \circ \langle \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_1}^A, \widetilde{\epsilon_{A+B} \circ f \circ i_2}^B \rangle = 1_{C^{A+B}}$.

Comment: You know, as long as you can justify we overall have a **natural** isomorphism $[X,C^{A+B}]\cong[X,C^A\times C^B]$ (natural in $X$), it follows from formal nonsense that there's an isomorphism. You don't need to manually check inverses

Comment: (btw $X\times(A+B)\cong(X\times A)+(X\times B)$ is a formal consequence of the existence of the exponential objects, it isn't always true)

Comment: oh yes I assumed we were in a cartesian closed category when i showed $X \times (A+B) \cong X \times A + X \times B$. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think natural isomorphism assumes knowledge of natural transformations. To be honest, I don't know exactly what I'm looking for. Since this problem comes before natural transformations in Awodey's textbook, I'm thinking there's a way to do it without natural transformations. But maybe in the end the only way to prove $C^{A+B} \cong C^A \times C^B$ is redoing the Yoneda proof but for a special case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine, let's get our hands dirty and not use the "nice" ways. This is a *terrible* way to think about things, by the way. The real content of the theorem is this: under the right conditions, $C^{A+B}$ satisfies the same universal property of $C^A\times C^B$ i.e. $C^A\times C^B$ *exists* and is modelled up to isomorphism by $C^{A+B}$. This is just chasing universal properties and is really not hard to see. However, the explicit computations are a good exercise in diagram drawing and there's also a secondary benefit: the below proof does not require existence of all exponentials $Y^X$ for arbitrary $X$ and $Y$ and all products $X\times(A+B)$, which the hom-chasing proof *does* secretly require; note also the hom-chasing proof also requires all products to exist, whereas here we only require existence of for the specific $C$, the exponentials $C^A,C^B$,$C^{A+B}$ and certain products involving them and $A,B,A+B$ as well as the exponentials $(A\times C^{A+B}+B\times C^{A+B})^{C^{A+B}}$ and $(A\times(C^A\times C^B)+B\times(C^A\times C^B))^{C^A\times C^B}$ (in order to say certain instances of $\phi$ are isomorphisms). So with a weakening of assumptions we get the same result. I doubt anyone cares about the minimal hypotheses for this though. Maybe some constructivist category theorists.

---

I use $\langle,\rangle$ and $(,)$ pairing notation to distinguish between coproduct and product pairings respectively. For instance, if $x:X\to Z,y:Y\to Z$ then $\langle x,y\rangle$ is the unique associated map $X+Y\to Z$. I use $\epsilon_X:X\times C^X\to C$ for the evaluation and if $f:X\times Z\to C$ then $\overline{f}$ is the unique arrow $Z\to C^X$ such that $f=\epsilon_X(1\times\overline{f}):X\times Z\to X\times C^X\to C$. Fair warning: this will be notational hell. All lines should be read with the accompaniment of a quickly sketched diagram.

$\phi:=\langle i_1\times1,i_2\times1\rangle:A\times X+B\times X\to(A+B)\times X$ is always an isomorphism because all exponentials exist. Let $\alpha:(Y\times Z)\times X\cong Y\times(Z\times X)$ denote the canonical isomorphism $(\pi_1\pi_1,\pi_2\times1)$. Let $\gamma:X\times Y\cong Y\times X$ denote the canonical isomorphism $(\pi_2,\pi_1)$.

There is an obvious arrow $f:C^{A+B}\to C^A\times C^B$ given by $(\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)},\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_2\times1)})$ and we want this to also be an isomorphism. There is an also obvious, but harder to explicitly notate, arrow $g:C^A\times C^B\to C^{A+B}$ given as the adjunct: $$g=\overline{(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})\phi_{A,B,C^A\times C^B}^{-1}}$$

To see $gf$ is the identity, it is equivalent to show the equality $\epsilon_{A+B}(1\times gf)=\epsilon_{A+B}$. Calculate: $$\begin{align}\epsilon_{A+B}(1\times gf)&=\epsilon_{A+B}(1\times g)\circ(1\times f)\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})\\&\circ\phi_{A,B,C^A\times C^B}^{-1}(1\times f)\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}\\&+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})(1\times f+1\times f)\circ\phi^{-1}_{A,B,C^{A+B}}\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A(1\times\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)}),\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_2\times1)}\pi_2)\\&+\pi_2(\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)}\pi_2,\epsilon_B(1\times\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_2\times1)})))\circ\phi^{-1}_{A,B,C^{A+B}}\\&=(\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)+\epsilon_{A+B}(i_2\times1))\phi^{-1}_{A,B,C^{A+B}}\\&=\epsilon_{A+B}\circ\phi_{A,B,C^{A+B}}\phi^{-1}_{A,B,C^{A+B}}\\&=\epsilon_{A+B}\end{align}$$The passage from the third line to the fourth used easy, but very horrible to write out in explicit notation, unravellings of how $\alpha,\gamma$ act and their naturality properties, as applied to $1\times f$. Anyway, we find $gf=1$.

In the converse, $fg:C^A\times C^B\to C^A\times C^B$ is the identity if and only if $\pi_1fg=\pi_1$ and $\pi_2fg=\pi_2$. The two cases are very similar, I'll focus on $\pi_1fg=\pi_1$.

$\pi_1fg=\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)}\circ g:C^A\times C^B\to C^A$. This map is $\pi_1$ iff. $\epsilon_A(1\times\pi_1)=\epsilon_A(1\times(\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)}\circ g))$. Calculate: $$\begin{align}\epsilon_A(1\times(\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)}\circ g))&=\epsilon_A(1\times\overline{\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)})\circ(1\times g)\\&=\epsilon_{A+B}(i_1\times1)(1\times g)\\&=\epsilon_{A+B}(1\times g)\circ(i_1\times1)\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}\\&+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})\\&\circ\phi_{A,B,C^A\times C^B}^{-1}(i_1\times1)\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}\\&+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})\\&\circ\phi^{-1}_{A,B,C^A\times C^B}\phi_{A,B,C^A\times C^B}\circ i_1\\&=(\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}\\&+\pi_2(1\times\epsilon_B\gamma_{C^B,B})\alpha_{C^A,C^B,B}\gamma_{B,C^A\times C^B})i_1\\&=\pi_1(\epsilon_A\times1)\alpha_{A,C^A,C^B}^{-1}\\&=\epsilon_A(1\times\pi_1)\end{align}$$As required.

Comment: ahhh i see. i got stuck because i said "let $f : X \times A + X \times B \rightarrow X \times (A + B)$ be an isomorphism." It actually mattered what f was( $f = \langle i_1 \times 1, i_2 \times 1 \rangle $), not any isomorphism works (maybe this has something to do with natural isomorphisms)

Comment: @CharlesGong Yeah, naturality is useful here. Also if you're going to resort to explicit computation, you kinda need to make sure *everything* is explicit; that requires understanding $\phi$ (I'm not saying this is some universal law, but, it is a good rule of thumb). Thankfully we didn't need to explicitly describe $\phi^{-1}$ but I think that's just because we got lucky